# Problem with initializing WebSocket server

Tags: node.js, typescript, http, ws

**Background**: I am absolutely new to NodeJS, but I have been trying to learn on writing app logic on behind the main HTTP/CSS user interface.

**Goal**: The idea is to create a simple http requests server that would handle incoming and outgoing requests..
It actually would be more of a HTTP listening server to handle POST(?) requests sent by another device, that would feed data from its sensors and use its own HTTP server to send that back to an APP. (I haven't learned much about REST, that is what I am trying to do rn).

**Clarification**: If my understanding is correct, then WebSockets handle the general IP/PORT communications and they act a bit like TCP, but with atomic operations (messages).

I read through some examples, so the majority of code is in fact based on what people suggest on the web. I tried changing the names and organizing it a bit. I wanted to try sending a UDP broadcast.

**Problem**: after making some changes the NodeJS interpreter will tell me about invalid WebSocket.Server constructor arguments.

```
TypeError: One and only one of the "port", "server", or "noServer" options must be specified
at new WebSocketServer
```

I looked up the class definitions in the modules directory, but I cant make much sense out of those (as I said, I am new to NodeJS and Javascript in general).

I also looked up my original (able to compile) file and can't fnd anything wrong with the

```
const websockets_server = new WebSocket.Server({ http_server });
```

To my understanding, the constructor may either accept:

```
options = {
  maxPayload: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
  skipUTF8Validation: false,
  perMessageDeflate: false,
  handleProtocols: null,
  clientTracking: true,
  verifyClient: null,
  noServer: false,
  backlog: null, // use default (511 as implemented in net.js)
  server: null,
  host: null,
  path: null,
  port: null,
  ...options
};
```

or a reference to an existing server object.

**Code**:

```
import {app, BrowserWindow}   from "electron"
import * as HTTP              from "http";
import * as UDP               from "dgram";
import * as WebSocket         from "ws";
import * as OS                from "os"

//CONSTANTS SECTION
var networkInterfaces = OS.networkInterfaces(); console.log(networkInterfaces);
const http_port       = 4444;
const udp_port        = 2137;
const http_server     = HTTP.createServer();
const udp_server      = UDP.createSocket('udp4');

//UDP
udp_server.bind(udp_port, undefined, () => {udp_server.setBroadcast(true);}); //bind is asynchronous and must be called before setting broadcast
var info = Buffer.from('Broadcast test message', "utf8");

//UDP SERVER SECTION
udp_server.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(`server error:\n${err.stack}`);
  udp_server.close();
});

/*udp_server.send(message, 0, message.length, udp_port, HOST, function(err, bytes){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('UDP message sent to ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
  client.close();
});*/

//WEBSOCKETS
const websockets_server = new WebSocket.Server({ http_server });

//EVENTS HANDLER ON WS
websockets_server.on("connection", (ws: WebSocket) => {
  //connection is up, let's add a simple simple event
  WebSocket.on("message", (message: string) => {
    //log the received message and send it back to the client
    console.log("received: %s", message);
    WebSocket.send(`Hello, you sent -> ${message}`);
    return true;
  });

  //send immediatly a feedback to the incoming connection
  WebSocket.send("Hi there, I am a WebSocket server");
});

//start listening on HTTP server
http_server.listen(http_port, () => {
  console.log(`Data stream server started on port ${http_port}`);
});

//MAIN APP
function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })

  win.loadFile("index.html")
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

PS: I read on the ":" (colon) operator's function in JS, but I can't see how it's working in this example. The guides say that it's used to reference properties (variables) inside structures. "message" seems to be a structure in "ws" (?) library, but I am not sure why one of those is referenced like "library: structure" and the other isn't.

Comment: shouldnt `new WebSocket.Server({ http_server })` be `new WebSocket.Server({ server: http_server })`?

Comment: I'm pretty dense.

I wanted to try that option out and forgot about it.

Yes, but what bothers me is that it worked without specifying the property previously.
Like this:
`const port = 4444;
const server = http.createServer();
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server })`

It got me confused, now it works without problems.
Weird.

In that case, it seems to be working. Thank you.